# Exiting child process

Tags: c, linux

I have the following code. It consists of a parent process and two child processes (a producer and a consumer). The producer accepts user input and passes it along to the consumer, which sums up the total number of vowels that have occurred. The parent process just listens to the two children processes and restarts them if they have stopped for whatever reason. The producer process exits when the user inputs 'p' and the consumer process stops when it receives a string that contains a 'y'.

The issue I am having is that the `_exit()` function call in the producer process is not causing the process to terminate. The `_exit()` function call in the consumer process works as intended. Why is the consumer process terminating correctly while the producer function does not?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main(){
    pid_t c_p, c_c;
    int p[2];
    pipe(p);
    c_p = fork(); 
    if(c_p > 0) c_c = fork();

    for(;;){
        // Producer Process
        if(c_p == 0){
            char c[20];
            printf("%s", "Enter a string: \n");
            fgets(c, 20, stdin);
            if(c[0] == 'p' && strlen(c) == 2) _exit(1);
            close(p[0]);
            write(p[1], c, (strlen(c) + 1));
        }

        // Consumer Process
        else if(c_c == 0){
            int j;
            static int a = 0, e = 0, i = 0, o = 0, u = 0;
            char buffer[20];
            close(p[1]);
            read(p[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer));

            for(j = 0; j < strlen(buffer); j++){
                if     (buffer[j] == 'a' || buffer[j] == 'A') a++;
                else if(buffer[j] == 'e' || buffer[j] == 'E') e++;
                else if(buffer[j] == 'i' || buffer[j] == 'I') i++;
                else if(buffer[j] == 'o' || buffer[j] == 'O') o++;
                else if(buffer[j] == 'u' || buffer[j] == 'U') u++;
                else if(buffer[j] == 'y' || buffer[j] == 'Y') _exit(1);
            }

            printf("Sum of Vowels... \tA: %d \tE: %d \tI: %d \tO: %d \tU: %d\n", a, e, i, o, u);
        }

        // Main Process
        else{
            int status;
            pid_t result = waitpid(c_c, &status, WNOHANG);
            if(result > 0){
                c_c = fork();
            }

            /*result = waitpid(c_p, &status, WNOHANG);
            if(result > 0){
                c_p = fork();
            }*/
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are four processes exist in your program after

`c_p = fork(); 
 c_c = fork();`

You can change it to this:

```
c_p = fork(); 
if (c_p > 0)
{
    c_c = fork();
    // Do something.
} else if (c_p == 0)
{
    // Do something.
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Almost there. The process now terminates correctly, but continually asks for input from the user. Is there some way I can get the program to stop calling printf()? I would have assumed it would stop after the process was killed...

Comment: OK, here's the problem, waitpid will return the pid of process ID of the child whose state has changed. It seems that you always fork a new consumer process no matter what input the consumer met. If you want to to terminate the consumer with input 'y/Y', change if(result > 0) to if (status == 0)